# How to replace the element in list of list by its ordering index

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, index, order

I have a list of list: `res={{9, 1, 5}, {3, 6, 12}}`
I want to change it to `res={{5, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 6}}`
by following their ordering index such that 1 to 1, 3 to 2, 5 to 3, 6 to 4, 9 to 5, and 12 to 6. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
res={{9, 1, 5}, {3, 6, 12}};

ArrayReshape[InversePermutation[Ordering[Flatten[res]]],
             Dimensions[res]]
(* {{5,1,3},{2,4,6}} *)
```

Comment: Similarly, alternatively, `res /. Thread[Flatten[res] -> InversePermutation@Ordering@Flatten@res]`.

Comment: Maybe post it as a separate answer? If I compare the two, I think your solution supports more general shapes, mine only supports arrays. And they behave differently when `res` contains duplicates.

Comment: Sounds good. Will do.

Answer (score 7):

A method that works for lists with arbitrary structure:

```
ClearAll[ranks]
ranks = Internal`CopyListStructure[#, Ordering @ Ordering @ Flatten @ #] &;
```

*Examples:*

```
ranks @ {{9, 1, 5}, {3, 6, 12}}
```

> ```
>  {{5, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 6}}
> ```

```
ranks @ {{9, 1, 5}, 3, {3, 1}, {3, {{{{6}}}, 12}}}
```

> ```
>  {{8, 1, 6}, 3, {4, 2}, {5, {{{{7}}}, 9}}}
> ```

Comment: Hi @kglr! Could you help me on this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276775/how-to-modify-the-axes-and-the-labes-of-my-plot

Answer (score 6):

Building off of [user293787](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/85954/user293787)'s answer, but possibly more general because it works for ragged arrays as well:

```
res /. Thread[Flatten[res] -> InversePermutation@Ordering@Flatten@res]
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer ;)