# How to modify the axes and the labes of my plot? (Specifically, to cut the vertical axis.)

Tags: plotting, labeling, frame, resourcefunction

I have the following data:

```
points1 = {{643.5, 120.856}, {659.5, 120.856}, {627.5, 117.866}, {643.5, 117.866}, {659.5, 117.866}, {627.5, 114.876}, {643.5, 114.876}, {659.5, 114.876}, {627.5, 111.886}, {643.5, 111.886}, {659., 111.886}, {630., 98.9023}, {644.5, 97.8793}, {622., 96.935}, {679.5, 96.935}, {636.5, 95.9121}, {665.5, 95.9908}, {650.5, 94.8891}, {643., 92.9219}, {649.5, 90.0104}, {619.5, 88.9088}, {635.5, 88.9088}, {657.5, 87.9645}, {606., 86.9416}, {643., 86.9416}, {679.5, 86.9416}, {620.5, 85.9186}, {665.5, 85.9186}, {634.5, 84.9743}, {650.5, 84.9743}, {643.5, 82.9284}, {657.5, 80.9612}, {643.5, 79.9382}, {674.5, 77.8923}, {611.5, 76.9481}, {627.5, 76.9481}, {643.5, 76.9481}, {659.5, 76.9481}, {688.5, 76.9481}, {652., 74.9808}, {680.5, 74.9021}, {614., 73.9579}, {630., 73.9579}, {666.5, 73.9579}, {644.5, 73.0136}, {622.5, 71.912}, {658.5, 71.912}, {636.5, 70.9677}, {650.5, 70.0234}, {628.5, 68.9218}, {673.5, 68.9218}, {643., 67.9775}, {659., 67.9775}, {606.5, 64.9873}, {643., 64.9873}, {620.5, 63.9644}, {665.5, 64.0431}, {681.5, 64.0431}, {634.5, 62.9414}, {650.5, 62.9414}, {574.5, 61.0529}, {643., 60.9742}, {659., 60.9742}, {588.5, 59.9513}, {604.5, 59.9513}, {620.5, 59.9513}, {687.5, 59.9513}, {703.5, 59.9513}, {635., 59.007}, {651., 59.007}, {673., 59.007}, {620.5, 56.9611}, {643.5, 56.9611}, {665.5, 56.9611}, {582.5, 56.0168}, {703.5, 56.0168}, {597., 54.9939}, {612.5, 55.0725}, {628.5, 55.0725}, {657.5, 54.9939}, {673.5, 54.9939}, {689.5, 54.9939}, {643.5, 53.9709}, {635.5, 52.0037}, {649.5, 50.9807}, {611.5, 50.0364}, {627.5, 50.0364}, {672.5, 50.0364}, {642., 49.0135}, {658., 49.0135}, {649.5, 47.0463}, {672., 46.0233}, {619.5, 45.9446}, {635.5, 45.9446}, {657.5, 45.0004}, {643.5, 44.0561}, {606.5, 41.0659}, {679.5, 41.0659}, {620.5, 40.043}, {636.5, 40.043}, {665.5, 39.9643}, {598.5, 39.02}, {651., 39.02}, {687.5, 39.02}, {612.5, 38.0757}, {628.5, 38.0757}, {673.5, 38.0757}, {659., 37.0528}, {643.5, 36.9741}, {596.5, 35.0856}, {625.5, 35.0856}, {677.5, 35.0856}, {610.5, 33.9839}, {647.5, 33.9839}, {663.5, 33.9839}, {633., 33.0396}, {602.5, 32.0954}, {618.5, 32.0954}, {655., 32.0167}, {671., 32.0167}, {640.5, 30.9937}, {626.5, 30.0495}, {663., 30.0495}, {587.5, 29.1052}, {603.5, 29.1052}, {648.5, 29.0265}, {618.5, 28.0036}, {634.5, 28.0036}, {670.5, 28.0036}, {686.5, 28.0036}, {656.5, 27.0593}, {605., 26.0363}, {642., 26.0363}, {619.5, 25.0134}, {664.5, 25.0134}, {680.5, 25.0134}, {633.5, 24.0691}, {649.5, 24.0691}, {641.5, 22.0232}, {657.5, 22.0232}, {574.5, 21.0789}, {696., 21.0789}, {589., 20.056}, {605., 20.056}, {621., 20.056}, {649.5, 20.056}, {665.5, 20.056}, {681.5, 20.056}, {635.5, 19.033}, {657.5, 18.0887}, {643., 17.0658}, {604.5, 16.0428}, {620.5, 16.0428}, {681.5, 16.0428}, {634.5, 15.0986}, {650.5, 15.0986}, {666.5, 15.0986}, {611.5, 13.0527}, {627.5, 13.0527}, {643.5, 13.0527}, {665.5, 12.1084}, {635., 11.0854}, {651., 11.0854}, {643.5, 9.11821}, {659.5, 9.11821}, {695.5, 9.11821}, {604.5, 8.09526}, {620.5, 8.09526}, {681.5, 8.01657}, {635., 7.0723}, {651., 7.0723}, {667., 7.0723}, {590.5, 6.12803}, {689.5, 6.12803}, {605., 5.10508}, {621., 5.10508}, {659., 5.10508}, {675., 5.10508}, {643.5, 5.02639}, {628.5, 3.13786}, {643.5, 2.03621}, {659.5, 2.03621}}

points2F = {{390.5, 53.0779}, {390.5, 50.0782}, {406.5, 50.0782}, {390.5, 39.0268}, {404.5, 36.9744}, {390.5, 36.0271}, {398., 34.0537}, {376., 33.0275}, {420.5, 33.0275}, {390.5, 32.0802}, {406.5, 32.0802}, {442.5, 30.0278}, {351.5, 29.0805}, {367.5, 29.0805}, {383.5, 29.0805}, {412.5, 29.0805}, {428.5, 29.0805}, {398.5, 27.9754}, {360., 27.0281}, {375.5, 27.0281}, {420.5, 27.0281}, {436.5, 27.0281}, {390.5, 26.0809}, {406.5, 26.0809}, {367.5, 24.9757}, {382., 24.0285}, {398., 24.0285}, {414., 24.0285}, {374.5, 21.9761}, {390.5, 21.9761}, {406.5, 21.9761}, {422.5, 21.9761}, {345.5, 18.9764}, {390.5, 18.9764}, {442.5, 18.9764}, {359.5, 18.0291}, {375.5, 18.0291}, {412.5, 18.0291}, {428.5, 18.0291}, {398., 17.0029}, {383.5, 15.9767}, {420.5, 15.9767}, {345.5, 15.0295}, {361.5, 15.0295}, {405.5, 15.0295}, {434.5, 15.0295}, {375.5, 14.0033}, {391.5, 14.0033}, {337.5, 12.9771}, {353.5, 12.9771}, {426.5, 12.9771}, {442.5, 12.9771}, {479.5, 12.9771}, {315.5, 12.0298}, {367.5, 12.0298}, {383.5, 12.0298}, {412.5, 12.0298}, {465.5, 12.0298}, {329.5, 11.0036}, {345.5, 11.0036}, {398., 11.0036}, {435., 11.0036}, {451.,11.0036}, {291., 9.97739}, {360., 9.97739}, {375.5, 9.97739}, {420.5, 9.97739}, {305.5, 9.03012}, {321.5, 9.03012}, {337.5, 9.03012}, {390.5, 9.03012}, {406.5, 9.03012}, {442.5, 9.03012}, {458.5, 9.03012}, {474.5, 9.03012}, {490.5, 9.03012}, {351.5, 7.92498}, {428.5, 7.92498}, {366.5, 7.53029}, {281.5, 6.97772}, {298., 6.89878}, {382., 6.97772}, {400., 6.97772}, {414., 6.97772}, {483., 6.97772}, {499., 6.97772}, {307., 6.03046}, {328.167, 5.97783}, {343.5, 6.03046}, {360., 6.03046}, {436.5, 6.03046}, {425.5, 5.87258}, {460.5, 5.87258}, {392.5, 5.00425}, {422.5, 5.00425}, {289., 4.92532}, {374.5, 4.92532}, {406.5, 4.92532}, {490.5, 4.92532}, {303.5, 3.97805}, {319.5, 3.97805}, {335.5, 3.97805}, {351.5, 3.97805}, {444.5, 3.97805}, {460.5, 3.97805}, {476.5, 3.97805}, {366.5, 3.03079}, {382., 2.95185}, {398., 2.95185}, {414., 2.95185}, {430., 2.95185}, {280., 2.00459}, {296., 2.00459}, {484.5, 1.92565}, {500.5, 1.92565}, {326., 1.45202}, {310.5, 0.978386}, {342.5, 0.978386}, {358.5, 0.978386}, {374.5, 0.978386}, {390.5, 0.978386}, {406.5, 0.978386}, {422.5, 0.978386}, {438.5, 0.978386}, {454., 0.978386}, {470., 0.978386}, {469.316, 5.87258}, {451.684, 5.87258}, {402.352, 6.97772}, {393.462, 5.00425}, {365.018, 7.02116}, {301.611, 6.03046}, {326.5, 0.978386}}

points3 = {{374.277, 120.856}, {390.221, 120.856}, {406.164, 120.856}, {374.277, 117.866}, {390.221, 117.866}, {406.164, 117.866}, {374.277, 114.876}, {390.221, 114.876}, {406.164, 114.876}, {374.277, 111.886}, {390.221, 111.886}, {406.164, 111.886}}
```

with the corresponding plot:

```
ListPlot[{points1, points2F, points3}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1.2, GridLines -> {None, {20, 100}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
PlotStyle -> {{Green, PointSize[Large]}, {Green, PointSize[Large]}, {Red, PointSize[Large]}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
FrameTicks -> {{Append[Range[0, 100, 20], {120, ">100"}], None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Now, I need to make the frame of my plot to look like the following; but I don't know how to do it:

[image]

Specifically, I mean:

**1.** To remove the labels on the horizontal axis, and plot two lines below each of the two groups of points and write under the lines: 8 h p.i. and 16 h p.i.

**2.** To write low, medium, and high on the right side of the frame.

and in particular:

**3.** **To cut the vertical axis above $100$ as in the figure in the above.**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows how to add a cut using [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/), see [@GustavoDelfino's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/276812/36508) for the other stuff.

We first save the plot to a variable:

```
plot = ListPlot[{points1, points2F, points3}, Frame -> True, 
  AspectRatio -> 1.2, GridLines -> {None, {20, 100}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
  PlotStyle -> {{Green, PointSize[Large]}, {Green, 
     PointSize[Large]}, {Red, PointSize[Large]}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Append[Range[0, 100, 20], {120, ">100"}], 
     None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

Now, using `PlotGrid`, we show the plot twice, and adjust the settings appropriately:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {plot},
  {plot}
  },
 PlotRange -> {Inherited, {{{101, 125}, {0, 100}}}}, (* inherit the horizontal range, and set
                   the vertical ranges of the two plots to only show the appropriate parts *)
 "MergeAxes" -> "Cut", (* add the axis cut indicator *)
 ItemSize -> Scaled, (* adjust the two parts of the plot to have 
                        sizes according to the shown plot range *)
 Spacings -> 15, (* the gap between the plots, needed for the cut indicator to show up *)
 AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio (* set the overall aspect ratio *)
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: @Marteen Can you give a more concrete example of where the styles are different? If I add `FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 15]` to the definition of `plot`, and add `FrameLabel -> {"x label", "y label"}` to the options of `PlotGrid` (as you tried), I get this result (notice how the styles are the same): [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLsMM.png)

Comment: @Marteen `FrameStyle` (as the name implies) changes the style of the frame. The `Black` colors font & lines black, the `15` is shorthand for `FontSize->15`. `Directive` is used to combine the two settings. What makes `FrameStyle` a bit "special" is that `PlotGrid` will copy the `FrameStyle` of the first plot for its own frame (which then controls the style of the labels specified for `PlotGrid`), see also the documentation of `PlotGrid`. You could of course also just specify `FrameStyle->Directive[Black,15]` in `PlotGrid` as well, but the other way makes sure everything looks the same.

Comment: @Marteen How are you adding the legend? If I use `PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Experiment", None, "Simulation"}, {Left, Top}]`, the legend doesn't get moved unexpectedly. As for removing the second legend: You can use `{{plot}, {First@plot}}` as first argument to `PlotGrid`, this will explicitly strip off the legend from the second (lower) copy of `plot`, leaving you with this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCxDk.png)

Answer (score 3):

The `FrameTicks` option can be further customized to help you get closer to your goal. For example try this in your code:

```
FrameTicks -> {
    {Append[Range[0, 100, 20], {120, ">100"}], 
    {{10,  Rotate["low", Pi/2], 0},
     {110, Rotate["high", Pi/2],0 }}},
    {{{Mean@points1[[All,  1]], "points1\nline2", 0},
      {Mean@points2F[[All, 1]], "points2F\nline 2", 0}},
    None}}
```

The broken axis are more difficult. Particularly on one side only. The easiest way is probably using the `"MergeAxes"` option of the PlotGrid resource function: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid

**UPDATE**:

This addresses the additional concerns in your comments:

```
ListPlot[
    {points1,points2F,points3},
    Frame->True, AspectRatio->1.2, GridLines->{None,{20,100}},
    GridLinesStyle->Directive[Black,Dashed],
    PlotStyle->{{Green,PointSize[Large]},
                {Green,PointSize[Large]}, 
                {Red,PointSize[Large]}},
    AxesOrigin->{0,0},
    FrameTicks->{
        {Append[Range[0,100,20],{120,">100"}], 
         {{10,Rotate["low",Pi/2],0},
          {110,Rotate["high",Pi/2],0}}},
        With[{mean1=Mean@points2F[[All,1]],
              mean2=Mean@points1[[All,1]]},
            {{{mean1,"points2F",0},
              {Mean[{mean1,mean2}], 
               Column[{"",DisplayForm@OverscriptBox[Pane["some text",150,Alignment->Center],"\[UnderBrace]"]}],0},
              {mean2,"points1",0}},None}]},
    BaseStyle->{Larger,Bold}]
```

[image]

Comment: Git it a try. I think you have the elements in my answer to achieve that goal.